# QFutureWatcher и ожидание main потока QT

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, асинхронность

Приветствую! Волнует одна большая для меня проблема которую никак не получается решить. Речь идет о многопоточности а именно пытаюсь реализовать отдельный поток при условии что главный поток будет ждать его выполнение главное не блокируя сам UI.
Пробовал много разных вариантов std а так же несколько вариантов из QT. На последнем на чем остановился, следующий код

```
template <class FUNCTION, class... Args>
auto runAsync(FUNCTION&& func, Args&&... args) -> decltype(QtConcurrent::run(std::forward<FUNCTION>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    QEventLoop eventLoop;
    auto future = QtConcurrent::run(std::forward<FUNCTION>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto futureWatcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>();

    QObject::connect(futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, [=]()
    {
        futureWatcher->deleteLater();
    });

    futureWatcher->setFuture(future);

    eventLoop.exec();

    futureWatcher->deleteLater();

    return future;
}
```

..

```
auto thr = runAsync([=]()
{
    QThread::currentThread()->sleep(5);
    //Sleep(5000);
    return "200";
});
```

Проблема заключается в том что главный поток якобы зависает при выполнении функции runAsync(..). Возможно кто понимает о чем я говорю и сможет мне помочь.
С Уважением

Comment: А Вам точно нужно "блокировать" main поток? QFutureWatcher прекрасно  умеет посылать сигнал, когда все завершилось

Comment: Я пытаюсь просто приостановить выполнение main потока. Главное чтобы майн ожидал пока выполнится future а потом мог работать с переменной которую поток вернул. Код предоставленный выше работает но UI зависает при выполнении future. Дело в том что если я не приостановлю main то переменная которую вернет функция из потока будет возможно пуста.

Comment: Очень похоже, что Вы решаете задачу неправильно.Не нужно блокировать главный тред, а любые попытки его "прокрутить" обычно приводят к разным спецэффектам (коллеги пытались, а потом удивлялись).

Comment: Насчет спецэффектов согласен, есть ли какая нибудь альтернатива? Как тогда можно не блокируя UI получить переменную которую вернет функция из потока? не выполняя главный поток или каким то образом подождать пока future вернет результат?

Comment: **Какую именно задачу вы решаете?** Сдаётся мне, что можно вынести ожидающий код из главного потока в дополнительный, а результаты пересылать в пользовательский интерфейс (то есть главный поток) через асинхронно подключенный слот. Но в вашем случае оптимальным может оказаться что-то иное. Может, вообще удастся избавиться от блокировки и положить пересылку результата на сигнально-слотный механизм.

Comment: Если оставить дополнительный поток работать вместе с главным то результаты которые нужно получить в главный поток, возможно будут пусты так как дополнительный поток не успеет выполнить задачу. Задача заключается в следующем. Нужно запустить код в отдельном потоке и результат должен получить главный поток при этом не блокируя UI.

Comment: Вам просто надо послать сигнал из дочернего потока в главный, обычный Qt сигнал.

Comment: Не до конца вас понимаю, расскажите поподробнее вашу идею как логика работать должна.

Comment: Я поспешил с комментарием, не внимательно прочитав Ваш вопрос и предыдущие комментарии. После того, как я это сделал, я перестал что-либо понимать. С одной стороны Вы пишите: «Я пытаюсь просто приостановить выполнение main потока» и тут же: «Код предоставленный выше работает но UI зависает при выполнении future». Вы делаете ровно то, что хотите, в чём проблема? Прокручивать event loop тут вообще не нужно, это просто лишнее (да и UI поток так не прокручивают, для этого есть `QCoreApplication::processEvents`). Блокировать UI поток нельзя, пользователи за это будут Вас ненавидеть.

Comment: В том то и дело что приоритет задачи не блокировать UI :)
но проблема заключается в том, если я сразу после запуска потока использую переменную в главном потоке которую он должен вернуть то она пуста по этому хотел бы услышать что скажут на это другие каким образом можно этого избежать.

Comment: "если я сразу после запуска потока использую переменную" - так не используйте! На крайний случай заведите какой то флажок, что переменная ещё не в валидном состоянии, пользователю показывайте крутилку. А когда future watcher отрапортует, что все готово, крутилку снимаейм и запускаем функцию, которая все обработает. Скорее всего Ваша загвоздка в том, что Вы боитесь разделить большую функцию на две маленькие.

Comment: допустим буду выводить крутилку. Проверю состояние переменной и тут опять же цикл. как же не блокировать этим циклом UI? QCoreApplication::processEvents не особо поможет. Не желательно было бы разделять функцию и кидать кусок кода под сигнал. Хотелось бы оставаться в пределах главного потока.